# Clarification about overriding in Java

Tags: java, terminology, overriding

Using this as an example:

```
class Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }
}

public class TestDog{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Animal a = new Animal(); // Animal reference and object
      Animal b = new Dog(); // Animal reference but Dog object

      a.move();// runs the method in Animal class

      b.move();//Runs the method in Dog class
   }
}
```

Is it right here to say upon calling b.move() the method "move() under the Dog class" has overridden the "move() under the Animal class" as the Dog object takes precedence when calling the same method when referenced by an Animal type?

Ive noticed many websites don't explain this, rather they just throw out examples without talking through the stuff line by line. Just want to clear up my terminology confusion.

A side note, would it be possible to have a Dog object but invoke move() which is under the Animal class? for example having something like:

```
Dog doggy = new Dog();
doggy.move()
>>>
Animals can move
>>>
```

Would this be possible? would ((Animal) doggy).move() accomplish this?

Comment: in addition use @Override notation, it prevents you from making
mistakes, like misspelling the method names in subclasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely, it is correct to say upon calling `b.move()` the method "`move()` under the `Dog` class" has overridden the "`move()` under the `Animal` class".

For the second question, you should implement the class Dog as:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

   public void move(){
     super.move();
   }
}
```

For the third question, the answer is "NO".

```
          ((Animal) doggy).move()
```

This is simply 'redundant' and give the output "`move()` under the `Dog` class".

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
    class Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }

   public void moveParent() {
       super.move();

   }

}

public class Main{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Animal a = new Animal(); // Animal reference and object
      Animal b = new Dog(); // Animal reference but Dog object

      a.move();// runs the method in Animal class

      b.move();//Runs the method in Dog class

      Dog doggy = new Dog();
      doggy.moveParent();

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **super** keyword to call upon the parents member functions or data members.

like: **super.move();** in this case you parent function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

From the [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

> If two or more independently defined default methods conflict, or a default method conflicts with an abstract method, then the Java compiler produces a compiler error. You must explicitly override the supertype methods.

So basically, if you're in the sub-class calling a method which is in the superclass, you won't be able to call the super-class' method unless you use `super.function()`. [Read up more on it here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's principle object oriented programming (aka OOP) - polymorphism. Dog, Cat, Elephant are all animal.

```
Animal d = new Dog();
Animal c = new Cat();
Animal t = new Tiger()
```

It must not care about, always right. :)